# delete lines not matching pattern

Tags: shell, awk

I have two files:
file1:

```
123,hj,0
345,788,0
```

file 2:

```
nmmnm,m kjlfkj jjljk(gjhgjh;id:123;)
klkl,nkklmk kljlk kjkn(vnbvmn;nbvbn;id:678;jlk;);
hgdsghhj (khj;id:345;)
```

I wanted to delete lines from file2 if the number between `id: and ;` do not match with column1 in file1.
Output:

```
nmmnm,m kjlfkj jjljk(gjhgjh;id:123;)
hgdsghhj (khj;id:345;)
```

Comment: Is the order important, or do you just want to skip lines with IDs that aren't present anywhere in the first file?

Comment: order is not important. if the line in file2 do not contain id in column1 of file1,delete the line from file2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First generate all patterns to accept, next, grep the second file:

```
cut -d ',' -f1 file1 | xargs -L1 printf "id:%s;\n"  | fgrep -f - file2
```

or, if you prefer split in two activities:

```
cut -d ',' -f1 file1 | xargs -L1 printf "id:%s;\n" > patterns
fgrep -f patterns file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}match($0,/id:[0-9]+/)&&substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-3) in a' file1 file2
nmmnm,m kjlfkj jjljk(gjhgjh;id:123;)
hgdsghhj (khj;id:345;)
```

This uses the first field of the first file to set keys in the array `a`. For the second file, `match` is used with `substr` to extract the part of the line that contains the id<sup>1</sup>. Lines are printed from the second file where the id is in the array.

<sup>1</sup>If `match` succeeds, the variables `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` are set to the start of the match and the length of the string matching the pattern. `substr` extracts the id, which is 3 characters from the start of the match.

Comment: The number after id is not 3 digit . It varies. The delimiter is ;

Comment: The "3" in the code does not refer to the number of digits in the id, it refers to the offset from the start of the string. The delimiter is not important. I have shown the output from the sample in your question. Did you try it yourself?